# how to run gunicorn+bokeh+flask script example (ubuntu)

Tags: flask, ubuntu-16.04, bokeh, gunicorn

I am trying to run the code below  (borrowed from: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.14/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_gunicorn_embed.py). in Ubuntu 16 but I cannot seem to get it to work. In a ssh, I entered `gunicorn - 4 flask_gunicorn_embed:app` and navigated to each of:
`127.0.0.1:8000`
`localhost:8000`
`"myhostname":8000`
but to no avail. The log says `Listening at : http://127.0.0.1:8000`. Can someone guide me on how to get it working?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.embed import server_document
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import BaseServer
from bokeh.server.tornado import BokehTornado
from bokeh.server.util import bind_sockets
from bokeh.themes import Theme

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('This script is intended to be run with gunicorn. e.g.')
    print()
    print('    gunicorn -w 4 flask_gunicorn_embed:app')
    print()
    print('will start the app on four processes')
    import sys
    sys.exit()

from bokeh.sampledata.sea_surface_temperature import sea_surface_temperature

app = Flask(__name__)

def modify_doc(doc):
    df = sea_surface_temperature.copy()
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

    plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', y_range=(0, 25), y_axis_label='Temperature (Celsius)',
                  title="Sea Surface Temperature at 43.18, -70.43")
    plot.line('time', 'temperature', source=source)

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        if new == 0:
            data = df
        else:
            data = df.rolling('{0}D'.format(new)).mean()
        source.data = ColumnDataSource(data=data).data

    slider = Slider(start=0, end=30, value=0, step=1, title="Smoothing by N Days")
    slider.on_change('value', callback)

    doc.add_root(column(slider, plot))

    doc.theme = Theme(filename="theme.yaml")

# can't use shortcuts here, since we are passing to low level BokehTornado
bkapp = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))

bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["localhost:8000"])
bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)

# This is so that if this app is run using something like "gunicorn -w 4" then
# each process will listen on its own port
sockets, port = bind_sockets("localhost", 0)
bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def bkapp_page():
    script = server_document('http://localhost:%d/bkapp' % port)
    return render_template("embed.html", script=script, template="Flask")

def bk_worker():
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    server = BaseServer(io_loop, bokeh_tornado, bokeh_http)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

from threading import Thread
Thread(target=bk_worker).start()
```

Comment: This is working for me fine on OSX so I have to assume there is some upstream issue to deal with/figure out. Best course is probably a GH issue with full details,

Comment: thank you, just so I'm on the right track, what is the URL you had to navigate to?

Comment: `localhost:8000` by default only "localhost" is allowed to connect via websocket, anything else needs explicit configuration.

Comment: thanks and last question I swear, `localhost:8000` won't work if ubuntu is on a virtual machine right? I would need to use the host name?

Comment: I'm not sure about Ubunt, but if you want to be able to use the hostname, you can pass it (in a list) to this parameter to `Server`: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/server/server.py#L66-L67

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the loopback IP explicitly:

```
bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["127.0.0.1:8000"])
```

And since this is a list, we can and may as well list multiple origins to cover other cases:

```
bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado(
  {'/bkapp': bkapp}, 
  extra_websocket_origins=[
    "localhost:8000", 
    "127.0.0.1:8000", 
    "127.0.0.1:80", 
    "127.0.0.1:443"]
  )
```

This was the first change I had to make to the example to get it to run on my machine.